# Can I stay on Drupal 7 forever?

Tags: 7

I've been using Drupal 8 for a while now and while it's not bad, it does slow down development a bit, as the whole framework is more strict. Which is a good thing to some, but I know of many people like me, who prefer having the freedom of easily creating modules, versus having to set up the new folder structure etc.

So my question is, can one survive without upgrading for the foreseeable future? And what is the longest time one can realistically go without upgrading?

Comment: Drupal has always maintained 2 branches, so 7 will likely be halted once Drupal 9 arrives. Hoewever the New 3 number version model of Drupal 8 should slow the need for Drupal 9 as API breaking changes can be introduced as part of the second version number. So you should be able to use 7 for quite some time to come. Perhaps even for longer if people step up to offer long term support.

Comment: [Backdrop CMS](https://backdropcms.org) is a fork of Drupal 7 and is very similar to Drupal 7. Most Drupal modules should work on Backdrop or be easier to port than porting to Drupal 8. It's not Drupal but maybe worth checking out. :)

Comment: Sure you can ***survive*** without upgrading Drupal ... think of all those people who have never ***heard*** about Drupal at all ... Maybe you should reword that part of your question ...

Comment: Uh, you can always switch to Backdrop CMS - a fork of Drupal 7 with a solid track record: https://backdropcms.org

Comment: Wasn't _exactly_ the question, or this answer needs to be expanded on.

Answer (score 2):

IF the current version of Drupal is working out for you and you don't need more features added than you can stick around on 7 for a long time.

The problem is that D7 will not receive any feature updates and most modules will not be updated for D7 aswell.

It is hard to say the exact date of when D7 will not be supported anymore but most likely in 3-4 years.

but the bug/security fixes will continue till the end of this year most likely.

source: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drupal-7-end-of-life/